# Python - How to create a user-defined function to convert an integer into a float-type number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, types

I need to create a user-defined function (`def`) that simply converts an integer into a float-type number. Here's the code I've been trying to do:

```
def conversion():
    num = int(input("Enter number: "))
    return num
    e = float(num)
result= conversion()
print("Result: " +str(e))
```

For example, if I entered `56` the expected result would be `56.0` but instead I got the error:`name 'e' is not defined`

Comment: I think you didn't post the whole code or is not well indented

Comment: `return e` and that should be obviously after the assignment to `e`. The `print` should be print `result`.

Comment: @Austin That should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problems**:

- You return `num` before you use `float`, so the returned value is always an integer.
- You print `e` outside function, but is defined in the local scope of the function.

**Corrected code**:

```
def conversion():
    num = int(input("Enter number: "))
    # return num
    e = float(num)
    return e

result = conversion()
print("Result: " + str(result))
```

Comment: Thanks again, in order to make it more concise I changed `return e` to `return float(num)` and thus removed `e = float(num)`. Essentially the same but in fewer lines.

Comment: Yes that should look good and concise, but doesn't add anything to its performance; sometimes I go explicit.

Comment: Wait, how about `return float(input("Enter number: "))` ?

Comment: It worked like a charm! You're the man. Would the opposite also work (converting from float to integer): `return int(input("Enter number: "))` ?

Comment: No, it won't work. For all above, make sure you enter only numbers or numbers with decimal. A string input will throw a `ValueError` which you may catch.

Comment: Thanks, I think I might know why. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, your problem is with indentation, here's what it should look like:

```
def conversion():
   num = int(input("Enter number: "))
   return num
e = float(num)
result= conversion()
print("Result: " +str(e))
```

Comment: It's not about indentation. :P